# Django: invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I want to insert some data into a many to many field. I 'm getting this Error

> user is an invalid keyword argument for this function

i also tried it with the relatedName...but still is not working...

My model looks like this:

models.py

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=False, blank=False, related_name='members')
    workspace_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
    workspace_cat =models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
db= Workspace(user=5, workspace_name=data_to_db['workspace_name'],workspace_cat=data_to_db['workspace_category'])
db.save()
```

Does somebody has an idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You used a [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) field for the `user` field of your `Workspace` object, you can't give it one user, that's not how a `ManyToMany` works, that would be a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

Basically, using a `ForeignKey`, each workspace has one `User` associated to it, there's a direct link `Workspace -> User`, so it makes sense to create a `Workspace` and pass it an `User`, like you would be filling in a `CharField`.

A `ManyToMany` relationship means that several users can be associated to a `Workspace` and several `Workspaces` to one `User`. When using a `ManyToMany`, you would create your `Workspace` and *then* add some `User`s to it.

To add to a `ManyToMany` relationship, do the following:

```
my_user = User.objects.get(pk = 5)
my_workspace = Workspace(workspace_name=data_to_db['workspace_name'],workspace_cat=data_to_db['workspace_category'])
my_workspace.save() # committing to the DB first is necessary for M2M (Jurudocs edit)
my_workspace.users.add(my_user)
```

You *should rename the `user` field to `users`* to make the relationship name clearer.

Comment: thanks for your answer... im my case i really want to  have several users be associated to a Workspace and several Workspaces to one User ;-P

Comment: @Jurudocs Then a `ManyToMany` is the appropriate use, please see my edited answer as to how to use it!